# HTML Table from .json file

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

So I'm really new to working with json files and coding in general. I've tried to wrap my head around this problem for hours now and I can't find any solution to it.

I have this .json file and want to make a HTML table from it:

```
{
   "template_commands":{
      "web":[
         "Webadded cmds are working!",
         "Rights['0']"
      ],
      "streamer":[
         "This is only for Streamers!",
         "Rights['3']"
      ],
      "admin":[
         "This is only for Admins!",
         "Rights['2']"
      ],
      "mod":[
         "This is only for mods",
         "Rights['1']"
      ],
      "taka":[
         "I love you",
         "Rights['2']"
      ]
   },
   "doggo_counter":0,
   "admins":{
      "tauru":"name",
      "jutlufa":"name"
   }
}
```

It should look a little bit like this:

| cmd_name | cmd | rights |
| --- | --- | --- |
| web | Webadded cmds are working! | 1 |

I don't need the "doggo_counter" or "admins" part of the file. Just the "template_commands. Is this even possible with that kind of file?

Comment: What have you tried already? I think something with a `json_decode()`, and `foreach()` or two would do it. Please post your code so we can help you figure out where the misstep is

Comment: Assume it is possible. do some research and have a go. then if you run into an issue come back with a [mcve] of the effort

Comment: Please don't edit solutions into your question. If you have solved your problem, you can post your solution as an answer. However, as your question is off-topic due to lack of focus, new answers cannot be posted. You asked below what the point of posting your code is: The point is so that your question has a narrow enough focus to be on-topic here. "How do I produce a table from JSON' is not a single problem, it's a series of problems that you should try to solve, and then post a specific question if you get stuck. The first step is parsing the JSON, if you're stuck there, ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php
$objs = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'),true);
$commands = $objs['template_commands'];
echo "<table border='1'>"; //table bordered
echo "<tr><th>cmd_name</th><th>cmd</th><th>Rights</th></tr>"; //the header of table
foreach($commands as $cmd_name => $cmds) {
    echo "<tr><td>$cmd_name</td>
    <td>$cmds[0]</td>
    <td>".preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','', $cmds[1])."</td></tr>";//only digits
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: That's good you pulled in the change for the Rights. The only thing that I would caution is that `$cmds[1]` could be an array. It depends on the JSON above and how it comes across.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that contain no *question*, just a list of requirements. You're not helping anybody by doing all of their work for them.

Comment: thank you for your notes about `$cmds[1]` as you said it really depends on structure of data in json file, and can i ask you why you delete your answer you fellow a nice approach by using `sprintf` and you minimize the code in a great way could you re-post it ?

Comment: @meagar I didn't mean to have anybody work for me! I've literally been sitting here for the last 5 hours trying to figure this out. Of corse I could have posted code into my question, but I had nothing even close to working. I converted the json to a string. that was about all I did, everything else I tried failed and probably would have caused more confusion than good. I'm sorry if I offended anyone or let it seem like I want others to do my dirty work, I generally want to unterstand. Thats why I asked if it even was possible with my .json file!

Comment: @meagar I've posted the solution and what I've done wrong in my post, i don't know why you think that giving someone a few lines of code is no help to anybody. If people do wan't to learn they need code that works to disect and understand imo. Especially if you are stuck on a problem for 5 hours and your brain is stuck on 500 lines of tried and discared code. There is no good in posting so many failed attemps.

Comment: @hppycoder Thanks a lot for your help! I posted your code in the question. If I missunderstood your code please feel free to correct me :)

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you should probably do that client-side with javascript.

What comes into my mind is using Vue, React or Angular, but if you are more the JQuery type of dev, there is this : https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32107/how-to-load-an-array-of-json-objects-to-datatables

I won't go into much technical details since your question doesn't show technical issues.